# My Python number guessing game

Tags: python

I have been trying to make a number guessing game for Python and so far it has altogether gone quite well. But what keeps bugging me is that it resets the number on every guess so that it is different, but I want it to stay the same and then people can take a while guessing it.

```
import os
import time

print("this is a random number generator")
number1 =int(input("please pick a NUMBER between 1 and 99"))
from random import randint
number2 = int(randint(1,99))
if number1 == number2:
    print(" congrats! you got it right")
elif number1 < number2:
    print ("too low try again")
elif number1 > number2:
    print ("too high try again")

if number1 not in range(1,99):
    print("you idiot! Pick a number IN THE RANGE")

while number1 != number2:


    print("this is a random number generator")
    number1 =int(input("please pick a NUMBER between 1 and 99"))
    from random import randint
    number2 = int(randint(1,99))
    if number1 == number2:
        print(" congrats! you got it right")
    elif number1 < number2:
        print ("too low try again")
    elif number1 > number2:
        print ("too high try again")

    if number1 not in range(1,99):
        print("you idiot! Pick a number IN THE RANGE")



time.sleep(10)
os.system("exit")
```

Comment: `number2 = int(randint(1,99))`  you keep generating new numbers in your while loop, so you have to take it out side the while loop.

Comment: If you have the answer you needed, please upvote them and accept one, in order to remove this post from the 'unanswered' queue.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have `number2 = int(randint(1,99))` inside your `while` cycle, then you create a new number each time. Put that line outside the `while` and the number will remain the same until someone guesses it

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code : the `import` statement should be at the beginning, and there is much duplicated code, which makes it hard to read.

**Your problem comes from the fact that `number2 = int(randint(1,99))` is called at each cycle of the `while` loop.**

This could be improved to :

```
import os
import time
from random import randint

print("This is a random number generator")
number2 = int(randint(1,99))
while True:
    try:
        number1 =int(input("Please pick a NUMBER between 1 and 99\n"))
        if number1 not in range(1,99):
            print("You idiot! Pick a number IN THE RANGE")
        if number1 == number2:
            print("Congrats! You got it right")
            break
        elif number1 < number2:
            print ("Too low, try again")
        elif number1 > number2:
            print ("Too high, try again")
    except (ValueError, NameError, SyntaxError):
        print("You idiot! This is not a number")

time.sleep(10)
os.system("exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, no need to import `from random import randint` everytime you need `randint()`. Put it at the top next to `import time`

Comment: Note that this is not an answer, but a comment or part of an answer.