# Python Guessing game - incomplete code

Tags: python

Can someone please help me re-design this code so that the program  prompts the user to choose Easy, Medium or Hard.

```
Easy: maxNumber = 10
Medium: maxNumber = 50
Hard: maxNumber = 100
```

It should choose a random number between 0 and the maxNumber. 
The program will loop calling a function the get the users guess, and another to check their guess. a function named “getGuess” which will ask the user for their guess and reprompt
if the guess is not between 0 and the maxNumber
r function named “checkGuess” which will check the users guess
compared to the answer. 
The function will return “higher” if the number is higher
than the guess; “lower” if the number is lower than the guess and “correct” if thenumber is equal to the guess. 
Once the user has guessed the number correctly the program will display all their guesses and
how many guesses it took them. Then the program will ask the user if they would like to try
again and redisplay the difficulty menu.

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! Welcome to the guessing game')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

while guessesTaken < 6:
    print('Take a guess.') 
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') 

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061474/guessing-game-in-python-attempts/39061594#39061594

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Python number guessing game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264447/my-python-number-guessing-game)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061474/guessing-game-in-python-attempts

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
from random import randint
myName = input("what's your name? ")
def pre_game():
    difficulty = input("Choose difficulty: type easy medium or hard: ")
    main_loop(difficulty)

def main_loop(difficulty):
    if difficulty == "easy":
        answer = randint(0, 10)
    elif difficulty == "medium":
        answer = randint(0, 50)
    else:
        answer = randint(0, 100)
    times_guessed = 0
    guess = int()
    while times_guessed < 6:
        print('Take a guess.')
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)

        times_guessed += 1
        if guess < answer:
            print('Your guess is too low.')

        if guess > answer:
            print('Your guess is too high.')

        if guess == answer:
            break


    if guess == answer:
        guessesTaken = str(times_guessed)
        print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

    if guess != answer:
        print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(answer))
    next = input("Play again? y/n: ")
    if next == "y":
        pre_game()
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
pre_game()
```